# No error details on remote requests MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm returning HTTPStatusCodeResult from my MVC action which is called via ajax.

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Msg Text");
```

Then inside ajax error function I want to read my custom status text using JS.

```
 error: function (xhr, status, error) {  }
```

Locally (request from browser installed on server) everything works fine but there is no custom message text when using remote machine. As you can see on ss below there is no custom message in statusText or responseText (it is there on local calls).
I have also added this lines to my web.config but it doesn't help:

```
<system.webServer>
   <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
   <customErrors mode="Off" />
</system.web>
```

Anyone has any idea why IIS is still blocking my messages?
Thanks in advance.

[image: xhr]